# Converting two loops to smarty

Tags: php, mysql, templates, smarty

I have two cycles in PHP, that I needed converting to smarty structure. Down includes PHP code.

Code:

```
<pre>
$query = mysqli_query($cnn, "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS ph FROM course INNER JOIN completed_course ON course.id = completed_course.id_course  GROUP BY course.id");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
    <tr> <td> <?php echo  $row['id']; ?></td><td> <?php echo  $row['nazev']; ?  </td><td>
    ?php echo  $row['ph']; ?  </td> <td>
    ?php
    $Number_of_graduates = mysqli_query($cnn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS abs FROM  participant where id_completed_course = $row[id]");
    while ($rAbs = mysqli_fetch_array($Number_of_graduates)){
    echo $rAbs['abs'];
} ?

</td>
</pre>
```

The question is. How to convert the second loop where first id from SQL?

Comment: Check out the [Smarty FAQ](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions). It's a good place to start when learning Smarty.

Comment: @Kryten I tried that. I have rather need, as the value of ID from the first SQL query to get the second query as WHERE. I have actually:   
`$mysqli->query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS ph FROM course INNER JOIN completed_course ON course.id = completed_course.id_kurz  GROUP BY course.id");
$data = $mysqli->fetch_all();


$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS abs FROM participant  WHERE id_completed_course = {DATA FROM FIRST QUERY}");
$data2 = $mysqli->fetch_all();`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so your question is really about SQL. Let's look at your queries. The first one looks like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS ph
FROM course
    INNER JOIN completed_course ON course.id = completed_course.id_kurz
GROUP BY course.id
```

I'm assuming (because I don't know anything about your database scheme) that this is going to give a list of courses and the number of students (maybe - I don't know what's in the `completed_course` table) who completed them. As written, this query is going to also give you some data from the `completed_course` table, but it's likely to be meaningless since you're grouping only on `course.id`.

The second query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS abs
FROM participant
WHERE id_completed_course = {DATA FROM FIRST QUERY}
```

Presumably, this query is intended to give you the total number of participants of completed courses. To make that work, the `WHERE` clause could look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS abs
FROM participant
WHERE id_completed_course IN (
    SELECT course.id FROM
    FROM course
        INNER JOIN completed_course ON course.id = completed_course.id_kurz
)
```

Notice that I'm taking the values selected in the first query and making them part of an `IN` clause. This query can be simplified significantly - for instance, the JOIN in the subquery is really only selected ID values from the `completed_course` table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS abs
FROM participant
WHERE id_completed_course IN (
    SELECT id_kurz
    FROM completed_course
)
```

And the query will actually be more efficient if you get rid of the subquery altogether and just join the participants to the `completed_course` table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS abs
FROM participant
    INNER JOIN completed_course ON participant.id_completed_course=completed_course.id_kurz
```

This last query is going to give you one value: the number of participants whose `id_completed_course` value corresponds to an item in the `completed_course` table. You can use the `mysqli` methods to retrieve this data and pass it to your Smarty template.